# How to filter aws security hub findings from ECR repository name using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-security-hub

Im writing a lambda function get AWS security hub findings and export it to another platform to analyze it. im using following code with boto3 to get the findings

```
securityhub_client = boto3.client('securityhub')
securityhub_client.get_findings()
```

it will return all the findings and its a very large json. i only want to get findings related to few ECR repositories and i tried to construct a filter object to get results im looking for. but im not exactly sure how to construct this filter object! can someone help with this issue

```
filter_expression = {
        "ResourceType": [
            {
                "Comparison": "EQUALS",
                "Value": "AwsEcrContainerImage"          
            }
        ],
            "ResourceContainerImageName": [ 
            { 
                "Comparison": "EQUALS",
                "Value": "nginx"
            }
        ]
        }
response = securityhub_client.get_findings(Filters=filter_expression)
```

above is a sample filter object i tried. i also tried replacing ResourceContainerImageName with ResourceContainerImageId and ResourceContainerName according to [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/securityhub/client/get_findings.html) but still no luck

Comment: Did you have that format/indent on your filter when you ran it? I doesn't look good.

Comment: @ErikAsplund sorry for the confusion! i just updated the question. i have used the filter object in the call. ResourceType filter is working but the ResourceContainerImageName is not